# Version control client that virtualizes files?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

My team's product version control repository (currently TFS) includes code, and also many large files (assets). I want to keep them there, so I can sync&build the whole thing in my official build. However, most developers don't need the assets to build locally, and sync'ing them just wastes disk space & time.

**Current solution:** Developers cloak specific folders, but that's a manual error-prone process. I'm looking for something similar to OneDrive in Windows 8.1 - where it creates "stubs" for files, and downloads them only when the file is actually accessed.

1. Is there such a client for TFS version control?
2. We're also in the middle of evaluating other version control solutions. Is there such a client for GIT, or maybe some other version control solutions?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Git, TFS 2015 Update 2 and beyond supports [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/). You can configure your Git client to either download the actual binaries from the Git LFS repo, or just download the stub files that point to your Git LFS store.

There is nothing equivalent for TFVC.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Git-LFS, and it seems to virtualize files at the *server*, not at the client. Maybe I misunderstood how to operate it...